# Can matrix transposition be considered as a change of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a given field $\mathbb{K}$ and positive integer $n$, can matrix transposition in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{K})$ be considered as a change of basis. In other terms, are there $P,Q\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{K})$ such that for every $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{K})$, $A^\top=PAQ$ ?

Comment: I think that is true only for some particular case and not in general

Comment: you want $Q=P^{-1}$ also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the case of $A=Q^{-1}$: we get
$$
(Q^{-1})^T=PQ^{-1}Q=P
$$
which is the same as $Q=(P^{T})^{-1}$, so $A^T=PA(P^T)^{-1}$ or
$$
(PA)^T=PA
$$
for all $A$.

This is clearly impossible: take $B$ a non symmetric matrix and $A=P^{-1}B$.

Answer (score 2):

No, because that would make $\ker(A^T) = \ker(A Q) = Q^{-1}(\ker(A))$ depend only on $\ker(A)$.  But $\ker(A^T)$ can be any subspace of $\mathbb K^n$ with the same dimension as $\ker(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are really two questions here.  First $V=M_n(K)$ is a vector space, it happens to be matrices but still a $K$-vector space.  And transpose is $K$-linear and invertible (it is its own inverse).  So yes, as a vector space transposition is a linear invertible function $V\to V$ and therefore a change of basis.  If you think of the unit vectors $E_{ij}$ then it is in fact just a permutation of the ordering of these, i.e. $E_{ij}^t=E_{ji}$. That is one reason it is tempting to think of this as transform as concerning a change of basis.

Now the way the second part of your question goes is not true.  The change of basis cannot be performed by simply multiply $PAQ$ (as demonstrated by @egreg).  The defect at the heart of this is that $(AB)^t=B^t A^t$.  Composing $A$ with other elements of the ring $M_(K)$ will remain in the ring, not suddenly take you to its opposite ring.  (Opposite rings are where you purposefully swap the order of multiplication.)

But there is a sense in which you are close to correct.  It is through the Skolem-Neother Theorem.  It says

If $\varphi:M_n(K)\to M_n(K)$ is a $K$-linear ring isomorphism then there is an invertible matrix $X$ such that $\varphi(A)=XAX^{-1}$.

As a corollary, if $\varphi:M_n(K)\to M_n(K)$ is any $K$-linear isomorphism where $\varphi(AB)=\varphi(B)\varphi(A)$ then there is an invertible matrix $X$ such that $\varphi(A)=XA^t X^{-1}$.

So in sense no transpose is conjugation, but any two transposes will differ only by conjugation.

Comment: For future readers: In the corollary, $\phi$ is not really an isomorphism, it is an ``opposite-isomorphism'' meaning it is a bijection that satisfies $\phi(A+B)=\phi(A)+\phi(B)$ and $\phi(AB)=\phi(BA)$.